# what are the last 2 digits of $n^n$ without computing the formula

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Computing this exponential is costly for number like $n=10^{400}$

Would rather find a way to find the answer without any exponentiation.

Comment: $10^{400}$ is simply a $1$ followed by $400$ zeroes. So the last two digits are $00$.

Comment: I didn't mean this number specifically.. I meant numbers in that range.

Comment: The numbers are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A000312/b000312.txt – you could have a look for patterns, then try to prove them.

Comment: Cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring?wprov=sfti1. For most of the $n$ you can take a short cut using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem?wprov=sfti1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last 2 digits of the result depend only of the last 2 digits of the original number.

Thus do all operations using modulo 100. Details about why we can simplify multiplication in modular multiplication see in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

- result1 = n mod 100
- result2 = (result1 * result1) mod 100
- result3 = (result2 * result1) mod 100
- result4 = (result3 * result1) mod 100
- result5 = (result4 * result1) mod 100

And so on, repeat it $n$ times. Thus you get the result very quickly.

Also you can write a simple Python script, that would be literally a few lines of code.

Comment: You might be right, but it is unclear to me that (for example) $(57)^{(57)} \equiv (157)^{(157)} \pmod{100}.$  Assuming that you are asserting the corresponding general congruence, and assuming that your assertion is accurate, I (for one) would ask you to prove this assertion within your answer.

Comment: @user2661923: Your interpretation is incorrect. $157^{157} = 57^{157}$, but not $57^{57}$. I didn't say that the degree (the number of repetitions) can be reduced. I said that we don't need to keep the whole number when we multiply, it is sufficient to keep only the 2 last digits.

Comment: quick proof of the claim that was actually made: $(n * 100 + k) * (n * 100 + k) = 10000n^2 + 200nk + k^2$. For integer $n$ and $k$ this is congruent, $\bmod 100$, to $k^2$. A similar proof (or induction) suffices for higher powers.

Comment: very good point.  this means that $n^n \pmod{100}$ (at least for the moment) can't be determined based on the result of $m^m$ for some $m < n$.  If I was able to misinterpret your response, perhaps the OP might also misinterpret your response.

Comment: In my opinion, the way to a *comprehensive* solution therefore involves finding the *order* of $n \pmod{100}$ for each $n \in \{0,1,2,\cdots, 99\}.$  This means that for each such $n$, determining $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that $n^r \equiv n^{r + k} \pmod{100},$ for any $r$.

Comment: No matter how large $n$ is, the value of $n^n \mod 100$ can be found by calculating $(n \mod 100)^l \mod 100$, for $l=1, \ldots, 100$. This is either a periodic function in $l$ for all $l$, or it converges to a periodic function in $l$ by $l =100$.

Comment: For example, $(1005)^{1005} \mod 100$ can be calculated as follows: $1005 \mod 100 = 5$. For $l \ge 3$, note that $1005^l \mod 100  = 5^l \mod 100 =25$.

Comment: @Mike Nice response.  This is what I was ultimately referring to.  Assuming that your assertion is true, I think that the proof deserves to be mentioned in (someone's) answer to the query, even if the answer is nothing more than a few lines of explanation that then refer to a theorem or proof elsewhere on the internet.  I also think that it is (**perhaps**) worthwhile reporting the pattern for each $n$ in $\{0,1,2,\cdots, 100\}.$

Comment: It doesn't mean that $n^n \bmod 100$ *can't be determined* from $m^m\bmod 100$ for some $m < n$; it means that mentallurg did not say that it *could*. For instance, $1000^{1000} \bmod 100$ can in fact be determined from $100^{100} \bmod 100$. If you don't like a solution, you can (possibly) edit it, or you can write your own, possibly better, solution. No need to critique anyone else's unless it's actually wrong.

Comment: I join in with @user2661923's criticism. It is  a stretch to interpret the statement of the first sentence to mean something other than claiming the same process to be applied to both the base and the exponent because in this problem they are equal.

Comment: Mind you, the Carmichael function of $100$ is $20$, a factor of  $100$. So for any $n$ coprime to $100$ we have $n^{100}\equiv1\pmod{100}$. Implying that $57^{57}\equiv157^{157}$. All because $157^{20}\equiv1$. The cases where $n$ is divisible by either $2$ or $5$ require a different treatment.

Comment: Actually, starting from my 2nd comment on (subsequent to this answer), I was **not** criticizing.  Instead, I was merely indicating that the OP might make the same mis-interpretation that I made, so the answer should clarify (for example) that it was simplifying $(1337)^{(1337)}$ to $(37)^{(1337)}$, but was not simplifying further.  In a subsequent comment of Mike, it was indicated/suggested that (for example) $(37)^{(1337)}$ can be simplified further.  My response was to ask that **someone** document the simplification.

Comment: @user2661923: I find your first comment good, because really - if you have misinterpreted the answer, so could do the others. After your first comment I have added a reference to Wikipedia that describes main rules of modular calculation.

Answer (score 3):

As another response has indicated, calculating (for example)
$(1337)^{(1337)} \pmod{100}$ is facilitated by noting that for any
$n \in \{0,1,2,\cdots, 99\}$ and any $r,k \in \mathbb{Z^+},$
we have that

$$n^r \equiv (n + 100k)^r \pmod{100}.$$

This means that computing

$$(1337)^{(1337)} \pmod{100}\tag1$$ is reduced to computing

$$(37)^{(1337)}\pmod{100}.\tag2$$

Expression (2) above can be resolved
via [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

It is known that $\varphi(100) = \varphi(4) \times \varphi(25) = 40.$

Given any $r \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, let $f(r)$ denote the unique element in
$k \in\{0,1,\cdots,39\}$ such that $r \equiv k\pmod{40}.$

Then Euler's theorem implies that
for any $a$ relatively prime to $(100)$
and any $r \in \mathbb{Z^+}, a^r \equiv a^{[f(r)]} \pmod{100}.$

Since (for example) $(37)$ is relatively prime to $(100)$ and $f(1337) = 17$,
you then have that

$$(1337)^{(1337)} \equiv (37)^{(1337)} \equiv (37)^{(17)} \pmod{100}. \tag3$$

So, the problem reduces to handling the $(60)$ elements in
$\{0,1,2,\cdots, 99\}$ that are **not** relatively prime to $100$.

$$\{a^b \equiv a^c\pmod{25} ~\text{and}~ a^b \equiv a^c\pmod{4}\}
\implies \{a^b \equiv a^c \pmod{100}\}.$$

Similar to the definition of $f(r),$ let $g(r)$ denote the residue of
$r \pmod{\varphi[25] = 20}$.

Also, let $h(r)$ denote the residue of $r \pmod{\varphi[4] = 2}$.

Then, the $(40)$ elements $n \in \{0,1,2,\cdots, 100\}$
that are relatively prime to $5$ but not relatively prime to $2$ can be handled
as follows:

For $r \geq 2, n^r \equiv 0\pmod{4}$ and $n^r \equiv n^{g(r)} \pmod{25}.$

In a similar fashion, the 10 elements $n \in \{0,1,2, \cdots, 100\}$
that are relatively prime to $2$ but not relatively prime to $5$
can be handled as follows:

For $r \geq 2, n^r \equiv 0\pmod{25}$ and $n^r \equiv n^{h(r)} \pmod{4}.$

Now, still unresolved are the $(10)$ elements $n \in \{0,1,\cdots, 99\}$ that
are multiples of $(10)$.  As one might guess, these are handled as follows:

For $r \geq 2, n^r \equiv 0\pmod{100}$.

**Addendum**
In accordance with a comment by Jyrki Lahtonen, who indicated (I have no way of confirming without doing further research - no thanks) that the
Carmichael number of $100$ is $(20)$ [rather than $\varphi(100) = 40$],
see also [The Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).